# Making the sftp server and still not know the cause of problem

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, sftp

I building a linux server and today I have a problem. I'm using ubuntu for user not ubuntu server.
My server use 2 ways to connect and use 2 different router

*1: Using an 4 ports LAN card to make a bonding mode, the router have gateway 192.168.1.1, the IP of bonding is 192.168.1.147 .The bonding is working good, I can easy connect to sever.

*2: Using normal internet port on mainboard, gateway is 192.168.5.1, IP for server is 192.168.5.11 . This connection use for SFTP server.

Check this pictures to see my connection:
[ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxPYp.jpg)   [ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rI0p.jpg)

I make a sftp server using openssh, here is my test case using filezilla:

- Connect to server via LAN ip 192.168.1.147 and external ip of router 192.168.1.1: working
- Connect to server via LAN ip 192.168.5.11: working
- Connect via external ip of router 191.168.5.1: not working

The result of not work test from filezilla:

> Status:   Connecting to 123.21.47.2:3389...
>
> Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>
> Command:  open "Deadlinesftp@123.21.47.2" 3389
>
> Error:    Network error: Connection timed out
>
> Error:    Could not connect to server

I have already do the port redirection on router, and this router work well with another windows server. I feel like something in ubuntu OS is blocking the connection via external ip of 192.168.5.1, I turned off the ubuntu firewall and still not work. I have to focus on 192.168.5.1 because this is the internet line use for ftp or sftp, can't use another one.

Does anyone here know why and can help me with this problem please.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add the output of `route -eF`

Comment: Check it here please https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtac8.jpg

Comment: you have to delete the first one (dest default, iface bond)

Comment: How can to delete that one. Sorry this is the first time I use ubuntu

Comment: `sudo route del default dev bond0`

Comment: OMG it working, thank you so much, you're my hero dude

Comment: Hello. I installed 1 more internet connection which have gateway 192.168.2.1 and lan ip 192.168.2.11 . That problem happen again with 192.168.2.1 . So do I have to delete 1 like you said or it have another way to use both 2 connection? Thank you https://imgur.com/xa5k1UY

Comment: there is a way, way too complicated too explain here. so youd better delete the new connection and then have some reading

Comment: Thank you. If you have link for that connection setup, please send me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that **you can only have one default gateway** and *you have two* and `enp5s0` is defined first, so that takes all traffic and `enp6s0` gets none...

That leaves you with the following possibilities:
(all are mutually exclusive, the higher the number, the more difficult)

1. You can have one of the two IPs face the internet (default) and the other one internal only. (static routes)
2. You need to add a 3rd external Internet router (E.G. A Cisco ISR 111x with dual WAN ports) that will bond the 2 external routers you already have and will save state for the external connections and set that router as the default gateway for both (on different IP addresses)
3. You can bond both NICs together and let the bond save state: *you have no control over what goes where: the bond does that for you* like the third router would do in hardware.
4. You can split up the internet in 2 and define **half of all Internet address ranges** on #5 (Let's say all of the USA; static routes) and all of the rest of the world on #6 (default).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no easy solution...

Comment: It's ok man, I understand. By the way, if i make an bonding with that 2 NICs so which bond mode should I chose ?

Comment: Now *that* would be a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) whereas [that one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1162811/344926) is definitely a duplicate of this one...  **:-)**
Give a full description in the new one of your current network config (iincluding drivers) and why you're trying to do this by posting a link to this one.  Tag it [networking] to have all the network gurus descend on your question like vampires...  **;-)**