# Netplan and multiple gateways

Tags: networking, server

I have a VM that I'm trying to setup with multiple NICs routing to multiple gateways. The goal is to have some docker containers use one interface and others to use the second, each with their own Gateway on my firewall, which will route the different networks to different WAN connections.

I have tried setting a default route for each interface to route to the respective firewall gateway IP but internet bound traffic still routes out a singular connection. I keep seeing that I need to use policy based routing but the examples I have tried to follow have not worked. Here is the current netplan config

```
network:
ethernets:
    ens160:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.20.140/24
        routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 192.168.20.254
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.20.138
            - 192.168.20.139
    ens192:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.90.100/24
        routes:
         - to: 0.0.0.0/0
           via: 192.168.90.254
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.20.138
            - 192.168.20.139
version: 2
renderer: networkd
```

How can I modify this to use policy based routing so if a container attached to 192.168.90.100 tries to route traffic anywhere (internet or internal) it will route to pfSense at 192.168.90.254 so that the firewall rules on that interface will determine what and where it can route? And the same for a container attached to the 192.168.20.140 routing to pfSense at 192.168.20.254.

I have tried this as well as I am seeing similar examples quite frequently and if I source a ping from ens160 to 8.8.8.8 it goes through no problem, if I source it from ens192 it gets no response.

```
network:
ethernets:
    ens160:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.20.140/24
        gateway4: 192.168.20.254
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.20.138
            - 192.168.20.139
    ens192:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.90.100/24
        routes:
         - to: 0.0.0.0/0
           via: 192.168.90.254
           metric: 100
           table: 90
        routing-policy:
         - from: 192.168.90.0/24
           table: 90
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.20.138
            - 192.168.20.139
version: 2
renderer: networkd
```

Edit:

I have now rebuilt the VM from scratch and followed this Youtube video exactly and pings and traceroutes from one of my interfaces still fail.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QmgQQ7wSpQ

config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.20.140/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.20.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.20.138,192.168.20.139]
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.90.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.90.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.20.138,192.168.20.139]
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.90.254
         metric: 100
         table: 101
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.90.0/24
         table: 101
```

IP rules and routing tables

```
    root@docker01:/etc/netplan# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.90.254  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens192
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.254  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens160
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens160
192.168.90.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens192

    root@docker01:/etc/netplan# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from 192.168.90.0/24 lookup 101
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

    root@docker01:/etc/netplan# ip route
default via 192.168.90.254 dev ens192 proto static
default via 192.168.20.254 dev ens160 proto static
192.168.20.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.140
192.168.90.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.90.100

    root@docker01:/etc/netplan# ip route show table 101
default via 192.168.90.254 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
```

Pings and Traceroutes

```
    root@docker01:/etc/netplan# ping -w 1 8.8.8.8 -I ens160
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.20.140 ens160: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

root@docker01:/etc/netplan# ping -w 1 8.8.8.8 -I ens192
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.90.100 ens192: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=10.0 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.043/10.043/10.043/0.000 ms
root@docker01:/etc/netplan# traceroute 8.8.8.8 -i ens160
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.20.254)  0.180 ms  0.168 ms  0.135 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
root@docker01:/etc/netplan# traceroute 8.8.8.8 -i ens192
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.90.254)  0.322 ms  0.161 ms  0.167 ms
 2  99.xxx.xxx.xxx (99.xxx.xxx.xxx)  0.731 ms  0.733 ms  0.743 ms
 3  172-8-212-1.lightspeed.bcvloh.sbcglobal.net (172.8.212.1)  10.522 ms  13.551 ms  2.325 ms
 4  71.151.85.76 (71.151.85.76)  2.347 ms  2.357 ms  2.793 ms
 5  75.25.192.162 (75.25.192.162)  3.598 ms  3.622 ms  3.456 ms
 6  12.83.69.33 (12.83.69.33)  3.539 ms  3.443 ms  5.023 ms
 7  gar26.cgcil.ip.att.net (12.122.99.93)  10.048 ms  10.150 ms  10.215 ms
 8  12.247.108.10 (12.247.108.10)  10.176 ms 12.247.108.6 (12.247.108.6)  10.041 ms  10.640 ms
 9  * * *
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  10.014 ms  10.483 ms  10.512 ms
```

The traceroute is making it out and the firewall is responding to the VM however Ubuntu is not accepting the responses it appears

```
    02:28:43.391272 IP 192.168.20.140.32811 > 8.8.8.8.33434: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391303 IP 192.168.20.254 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
02:28:43.391312 IP 192.168.20.140.53464 > 8.8.8.8.33435: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391327 IP 192.168.20.254 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
02:28:43.391366 IP 192.168.20.140.57078 > 8.8.8.8.33436: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391380 IP 192.168.20.254 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
02:28:43.391411 IP 192.168.20.140.35667 > 8.8.8.8.33437: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391454 IP 192.168.20.140.45787 > 8.8.8.8.33438: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391534 IP 192.168.20.140.53900 > 8.8.8.8.33439: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391579 IP 192.168.20.140.37268 > 8.8.8.8.33440: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391615 IP 192.168.20.140.51044 > 8.8.8.8.33441: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391644 IP 192.168.20.140.50215 > 8.8.8.8.33442: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391681 IP 192.168.20.140.46789 > 8.8.8.8.33443: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391709 IP 192.168.20.140.57053 > 8.8.8.8.33444: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391739 IP 192.168.20.140.33078 > 8.8.8.8.33445: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391780 IP 192.168.20.140.37907 > 8.8.8.8.33446: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391838 IP 192.168.20.140.36701 > 8.8.8.8.33447: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391889 IP 192.168.20.140.49202 > 8.8.8.8.33448: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.391921 IP 192.168.20.140.51706 > 8.8.8.8.33449: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.392129 IP 99.xxx.xxx.xxx > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.392229 IP 99.xxx.xxx.xxx > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.392280 IP 99.xxx.xxx.xxx > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.393897 IP 172.8.212.1 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.393947 IP 71.151.85.76 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.393999 IP 71.151.85.76 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.394458 IP 71.151.85.76 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.394502 IP 172.8.212.1 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.395366 IP 75.25.192.162 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.395408 IP 75.25.192.162 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.395450 IP 75.25.192.162 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.397479 IP 12.83.69.33 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:43.399102 IP 172.8.212.1 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:43.435955 IP 192.168.20.140.56092 > 8.8.8.8.33450: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.435990 IP 192.168.20.140.46658 > 8.8.8.8.33451: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.436027 IP 192.168.20.140.48041 > 8.8.8.8.33452: UDP, length 32
02:28:43.441689 IP 12.83.69.33 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:43.441736 IP 12.83.69.33 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:43.446278 IP 12.122.99.93 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:48.397320 IP 192.168.20.140.42424 > 8.8.8.8.33453: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397392 IP 192.168.20.140.47355 > 8.8.8.8.33454: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397406 IP 192.168.20.140.38424 > 8.8.8.8.33455: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397446 IP 192.168.20.140.44780 > 8.8.8.8.33456: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397500 IP 192.168.20.140.40787 > 8.8.8.8.33457: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397552 IP 192.168.20.140.37721 > 8.8.8.8.33458: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397592 IP 192.168.20.140.34060 > 8.8.8.8.33459: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397624 IP 192.168.20.140.50530 > 8.8.8.8.33460: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397663 IP 192.168.20.140.33608 > 8.8.8.8.33461: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397693 IP 192.168.20.140.38658 > 8.8.8.8.33462: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397746 IP 192.168.20.140.34202 > 8.8.8.8.33463: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397803 IP 192.168.20.140.33192 > 8.8.8.8.33464: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.397834 IP 192.168.20.140.34811 > 8.8.8.8.33465: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.407230 IP 12.122.99.93 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:48.407282 IP 12.122.99.93 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
02:28:48.407655 IP 12.247.108.10 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:48.407701 IP 12.247.108.10 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:48.407742 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33462 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.407780 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33461 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.407822 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33465 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.407864 IP 12.247.108.6 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
02:28:48.407905 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33464 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.407941 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33463 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.435687 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.20.254 tell 192.168.20.140, length 46
02:28:48.435693 ARP, Reply 192.168.20.254 is-at 00:1b:21:a7:9d:30, length 28
02:28:48.437096 IP 192.168.20.140.39427 > 8.8.8.8.33466: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.437143 IP 192.168.20.140.60584 > 8.8.8.8.33467: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.437174 IP 192.168.20.140.55572 > 8.8.8.8.33468: UDP, length 32
02:28:48.447080 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33468 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.447126 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33466 unreachable, length 36
02:28:48.447168 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33467 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.403576 IP 192.168.20.140.43095 > 8.8.8.8.33469: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403609 IP 192.168.20.140.41627 > 8.8.8.8.33470: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403636 IP 192.168.20.140.43791 > 8.8.8.8.33471: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403675 IP 192.168.20.140.39186 > 8.8.8.8.33472: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403704 IP 192.168.20.140.48563 > 8.8.8.8.33473: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403749 IP 192.168.20.140.42067 > 8.8.8.8.33474: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403802 IP 192.168.20.140.59170 > 8.8.8.8.33475: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403850 IP 192.168.20.140.59998 > 8.8.8.8.33476: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403890 IP 192.168.20.140.52793 > 8.8.8.8.33477: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403933 IP 192.168.20.140.51695 > 8.8.8.8.33478: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.403967 IP 192.168.20.140.54739 > 8.8.8.8.33479: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.404002 IP 192.168.20.140.55102 > 8.8.8.8.33480: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.404032 IP 192.168.20.140.47632 > 8.8.8.8.33481: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.413626 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33469 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413702 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33470 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413740 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33473 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413777 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33474 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413814 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33475 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413854 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33476 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413893 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33471 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413933 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33477 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.413975 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33478 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.414021 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33472 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.414105 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33479 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.414146 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33480 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.414185 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33481 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.438326 IP 192.168.20.140.38862 > 8.8.8.8.33482: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.438409 IP 192.168.20.140.48652 > 8.8.8.8.33483: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.438469 IP 192.168.20.140.46369 > 8.8.8.8.33484: UDP, length 32
02:28:53.448139 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33482 unreachable, length 36
02:28:53.448202 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.140: ICMP 8.8.8.8 udp port 33484 unreachable, length 36
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** You have two NICS with two default gateways.  You can only have one. See [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163632/344926)